# How to fit/shift and measure similarity of 2 time series in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a given signal `given` and a measurement time series `measured`.

The given signal was originally in another frequency, I managed to convert it into the correct timestamps, but I am stuck in how I could "match" the signal to the measurements together and calculate their "similarity", I would use dynamic time warping or correlation with `np.correlate` in that regard.

So the actual data consists of roughly 700k datapoints. However, I tried to replicate the data on a smaller scale with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"measured": [20, 20, 9.8, 10.1, 4.8, 4.9, 9.7, 9.9, 2.9, 3.0, 3.1, 10.1, 10.0, 20, 20],
                   "given": [np.nan, 10, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 3, 3, 3, 10, 10,np.nan, np.nan, np.nan,]},
                  index=pd.date_range("2018-01-01", periods=15, freq="s"))
```

Which looks like this:

```
                      measured  given
2018-01-01 00:00:00     20.0    NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:01     20.0    10.0
2018-01-01 00:00:02     9.8     10.0
2018-01-01 00:00:03     10.1    5.0
2018-01-01 00:00:04     4.8     5.0
2018-01-01 00:00:05     4.9     10.0
2018-01-01 00:00:06     9.7     10.0
2018-01-01 00:00:07     9.9     3.0
2018-01-01 00:00:08     2.9     3.0
2018-01-01 00:00:09     3.0     3.0
2018-01-01 00:00:10     3.1     10.0
2018-01-01 00:00:11     10.1    10.0
2018-01-01 00:00:12     10.0    NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:13     20.0    NaN
2018-01-01 00:00:14     20.0    NaN
```

[image: Click here to see image]

I was thinking about calculating their similarity and their lag and solve it by iteration to find the optimal solution/best similarity. How would one implement this?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you're looking for here is `Dynamic Time Warping`. This will match 2 signals without having the constraint of matching them on the same timestamp. There are modules created that can do this for you, for example, [Darts](https://unit8co.github.io/darts/examples/13-Dynamic-Time-Warping-example.html?highlight=time%20warping) has that utility and a tutorial on how to implement it.

Here is a quick visual explanation to DTW:
[image]